# Custom HTML Add-on for Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for an extension/add-on for Chrome or Firefox (better yet, both!) that allows the user to customize the HTML for certain domains. I know they have these tools for CSS code (like Stylebot), but I can't find one for HTML.

Answer (score 1):

[Greasemonkey for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)

That should do it.

Comment: There's a version for Chrome as well: http://www.mychromeaddons.com/chrome-addon-greasemetal-greasemonkey-for-chrome/